# Facebook4j authentication issue

Tags: java, json, facebook, import

I am trying to make a java app which makes connection with facebook.I am using facebok4j to achieve this,I made an app in fb devolopers and got the key annd id for it.But when i am passing it to get an access token its returning an exception error.Please help me

java code

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import net.sf.json.JSONArray; 
import net.sf.json.JSONObject; 
import facebook4j.Facebook; 
import facebook4j.FacebookException; 
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory; 
import facebook4j.Post; 
import facebook4j.ResponseList;
import facebook4j.auth.AccessToken;
import facebook4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization;
import facebook4j.auth.OAuthSupport;
import facebook4j.conf.Configuration; 
import facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder; 
public class Fbsample {
public static  Configuration createConfiguration() 
{
    ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
    confBuilder.setOAuthAppId("*****");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret("*****");
    confBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
    confBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build();
    return configuration;
}
public static void main(String[] argv) throws FacebookException {
    Configuration configuration =  createConfiguration();
    FacebookFactory facebookFactory = new FacebookFactory(configuration );
    Facebook facebookClient = facebookFactory.getInstance();
    AccessToken accessToken = null;
    try{
        OAuthSupport oAuthSupport = new OAuthAuthorization(configuration );
        accessToken = oAuthSupport.getOAuthAppAccessToken();

    }catch (FacebookException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while creating access token " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    facebookClient.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
//results in an error says {An active access token must be used to query information about the current user}
}
```

}

For now i specified my token and id as *.When running its returning 'Error while creating access token graph.facebook.com'.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output the whole exception object, and see if it contains any more useful information about the error.

Comment: FacebookException{statusCode=400, errorType='null', errorMessage='null', errorCode=-1, errorSubcode=-1, version=2.4.8}

Comment: Hm, that isn’t much useful. Seems to be a very generic error. Only advice I can give is double-check your app id and secret and other configuration options.

Comment: What type of access token are you trying to get here? If it is not just an app access token, then you need to log the user in before.

Comment: Now it's working...it's because of the credentials which i provided.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make this work for a user instead of an app.

Comment: You’d start by having the user login to your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/